# Field length is > maximum

Tags: c#, odbc, pervasive-sql

I'm working on some middleware in C# using the System.Data.Odbc library to interact with a v10 PSQL database. I have a set of working select and insert queries I run in sequence where occasionally the full sequence will execute without issue but most of the time for each INSERT query in the sequence my error handling catches the exception:

**ERROR [HY000][Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Date Record Manager]Field length is > maximum**

I'm trying to understand what this means and how to resolve it.

This is on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I'm using C# in Visual Studios Community 2015 to take information from a web system (no issues here) and add sales orders to the other system sitting on the server which uses a Pervasive SQL v10 database.

The PSQL tables are massive with 80-160 columns, so for the 3 tables I need to write to I run a select query first to fetch the excess values, then bind them as parameters for the insert query. There are 4 SELECT/INSERT routines run in sequence, with the last one running n times in a foreach loop.

I've been able to run this ODBC SELECT/INSERT sequence on this system in the past using MS Access and PHP. I've tried cleaning the solution, rebooting the server and rebuilding, as well as adding additional Dispose() calls on the commands, but I still get these errors.

```
class PSQLOrderConnector
{
    private OdbcConnection Odbc { get; }

    public PSQLOrderConnector()
    {
        Odbc = new OdbcConnection(Constants.ODBCSTRING);
        Odbc.Open();
    }

    /*
    ...
    */

    public void CreateOrderAddressBillTo(string CustomerCode, string OrderNumber, string AddDate, int AddTime)
    {
        OdbcCommand cmdSelectAddressB = new OdbcCommand();
        OdbcCommand cmdInsertAddressB = new OdbcCommand();

        cmdSelectAddressB = this.Odbc.CreateCommand();

        cmdSelectAddressB.CommandText = OrderQueries.PQSL_SELECT_ADDRESS_BY_CUSTOMER;
        cmdSelectAddressB.Parameters.Add("@CEV_NO", OdbcType.Text).Value = CustomerCode;

        OdbcDataReader reader = cmdSelectAddressB.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Read();

        var NAME = reader.GetString(0);
        /* ...repeat for the next 80 columns */

        cmdSelectAddressB.Dispose();

        cmdInsertAddressB = this.Odbc.CreateCommand();

        cmdInsertAddressB.CommandText = OrderQueries.PSQL_INSERT_ORDER_ADDRESS;
        cmdInsertAddressB.Parameters.Add("NAME", OdbcType.Text).Value = NAME;
        /* ...repeat for the next 80 variables */

        try
        {
            int result = cmdInsertAddressB.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OdbcException odbce)
        {
            //Exception error gets thrown here
        }

        cmdInsertAddressB.Dispose();
    }

    /*
    ...
    */
}       

class Order
{
    private PSQLOrderConnector PSQLOrder { get; }   

    public Order()
    {
        PSQLOrder = new PSQLOrderConnector();
    }       
    /*
    ...
    */

    public void AddOrders(List<businessEvent> Events )
    {
        /*
        ...
        */

        /* These 4 calls either pass in sequence or fail in sequence on the Try/Catch in the above class*/
        PSQLOrder.CreateOrderHeader(OrderNumber, CustomerCode, PONumber, SubTotal, CurrentCost, AverageCost, AddDate, AddTime);

        /* This is the method detailed above */
        PSQLOrder.CreateOrderAddressBillTo(CustomerCode, OrderNumber, AddDate, AddTime);

        PSQLOrder.CreateOrderAddressShipTo(CustomerCode, ShipToCode, OrderNumber, AddDate, AddTime);

        int recNo = 1;
        foreach (ItemLine line in itemLines)
        {
            PSQLOrder.CreateOrderDetail( OrderNumber, recNo, line.ItemCode, line.Quantity, line.Price, AddDate, AddTime);
            recNo++;
        }       
    }
}
```

(I edited the code for cleaner posting here, hopefully there's no typo's)

With the last lines running the function calls either the error triggers for each insert in sequence, or the entire sequence completes successfully. Using the same or different inputs this occurs randomly with roughly a 80/20 failure/success rate.

Comment: Have you identified which fields are causing the error?  What does the actual INSERT statement look like? Are you setting all fields to the "OdbcType.Text" or are you setting them specifically?  If you're setting them all to the same value, are you checking the length of the value that's being inserted and making sure that it's less than the maximum?

Comment: When you get a general fail error it's hard to pinpoint a specific field when there are just so damn many, but you got me thinking and I was able to pinpoint and verify the culprit. There are two common parameters that I'm passing to each insert: AddDate and AddTime. The code I posted indicates but doesn't show directly that I set these once then pass it to each function, and the culprit was the time stamp. The PSQL DB has a bit of an archaic way of storing the time stamp and cannot exceed 8 digits, which since I set it once explains why the whole thing would fail but sometimes it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue, the error message was exactly right and was pointing to my timestamp. Because I set it once with a variable AddTime then sent that to each of the 4 function calls is why it would fail in sequence but sometimes work, probably in the first 9 seconds of the system minute.